# Segmentation fault with Python with install of PyICU

Tags: python, importerror, glibc, icu, pyicu

I have been trying to install a Python library called Polyglot, which in turn requires PyICU, the source of my woes. After a wild goose chase of errors, I was able to install PyICU on my EC2 instance. However, when running Polyglot, and in turn PyICU, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/anaconda3/bin/polyglot", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('polyglot==16.7.4', 'console_scripts', 'polyglot')()
  File "/mnt/data/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 487, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/mnt/data/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2728, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/mnt/data/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/mnt/data/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2352, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/mnt/data/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from icu import Locale
  File "/mnt/data/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/icu/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from _icu import *
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
```

To resolve the above issue, I performed the following steps:

```
mkdir ~/glibc_install; cd ~/glibc_install 
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.18.tar.gz
tar zxvf glibc-2.18.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.18
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.18
make -j4
make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.18/lib
```

But then when I simply ran Python, I got an immediate segmentation fault.

Note that I am using Red Hat 7.1.2-2 on an AWS EC2.

Any help at all would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to experiment, you could use the beta of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8, which comes with glibc 2.28 and therefore provides the `GLIBC_2.18` symbols.

The segmentation fault will go away if you run Python with an explicitly loader invocation (such as `/opt/glibc-2.18/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 python …`).  If you want go into this direction, you should really use a more recent version of glibc still maintained upstream (such as glibc 2.28 at this time), and ideally a release branch from Git because it has many backports to fix various bugs.

But the next problem is that you are trying to replace the system libstdc++ library with a custom copy.  This can break system software and third-party applications.

You should try to get a copy of the software you are trying to install that has been built for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (or even Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6).  It will be much easier to use, and avoid all these issues.  If the software is written using a newer C++ standard than C++98, you can use [Developer Toolset](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/overview/).  It has a hybrid linking model, statically linking support code needed for newer C++ standard, while still using the system libstdc++ for the rest, to maximize interoperability.